# how to make user control draggable only from specific places

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

im working now on a `UserControl` which ive made draggable using the code below (which is quite known and used). This `UserControl` looks and is used in a similar to `MessageBox` (the gray color and the blue rectangle) , the task is to make this `UserControl` draggable only from the blue rectangle just as any `MessageBox` , not as its now draggable from any place inside it!

any suggestions on how to be able to do this? thanks in advance!

below the code used to drag the `UserControl`

```
 public UserControl1(Data  data, Settings settings)
 {


        InitializeComponent();
        MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(root_MouseLeftButtonDown);
        MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(root_MouseLeftButtonUp);
        MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(root_MouseMove);
}

...



 private void root_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

            var element = sender as FrameworkElement;
            anchorPoint = e.GetPosition(null);

            element.CaptureMouse();
            isInDrag = true;
            e.Handled = true;

        }



   private void root_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isInDrag)
            {
                var element = sender as FrameworkElement;
                element.ReleaseMouseCapture();
                isInDrag = false;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }


        private void root_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isInDrag)
            {

                var element = sender as FrameworkElement;
                currentPoint = e.GetPosition(null);


                UIElement parentElement = (UIElement)this.Parent;

                maxHeightParent = parentElement.RenderSize.Height;
                maxWidthParent = parentElement.RenderSize.Width;

                maxHeight = RenderSize.Height;
                maxWidth = RenderSize.Width;

                //Window.ActualHeightProperty


                //element.ActualHeight

                transform.X += (currentPoint.X - anchorPoint.X);


                transform.Y += (currentPoint.Y - anchorPoint.Y);

                this.RenderTransform = transform;
                anchorPoint = currentPoint;
            }

        }




    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to solve this, which are actually the same way with different syntax:

1. Via code - in the constructor, instead of

   ```
   MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(root_MouseLeftButtonDown);
   MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(root_MouseLeftButtonUp);
   MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(root_MouseMove);
   ```

   use

   ```
   myBlueRect.MouseLeftButtonDown += 
              new MouseButtonEventHandler(root_MouseLeftButtonDown);`
   myBlueRect.MouseLeftButtonUp += 
              new MouseButtonEventHandler(root_MouseLeftButtonUp);
   myBlueRect.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(root_MouseMove);
   ```
2. Via XAML - in the tag of the relevant element that you want to grag from (lets say it's a `Grid`):

   ```
   <Grid x:Name="myBlueRect"
         MouseLeftButtonDown="root_MouseLeftButtonDown" 
         MouseLeftButtonUp="root_MouseLeftButtonUp"
         MouseMove="root_MouseMove"
         .../>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Two basic options I think about:

1. Inside your UserControl make the rectangle a Border (or other control), and put the events on this Border and not on the UserControl.
2. If from some reason you do want the events to be on the UserControl, put a Hidden Border on the place of the rectangle, and in the event do the dragging only if the mouse is over this Border.